# javascript function to remove null value

Tags: javascript

am trying to remove null value in listbox so first i tried with loop and then one guy helped to do this way but its not removing a null value and empty space...can some body 
help out this problem by javascript..

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function change()
{
    //document.getElementById("Geography").options[7]=new Option("", "newval", true, false);

    var optionsArr = [];
    optionsArr.push(document.getElementById("Geography").options);
    optionsArr.push(document.getElementById("zone").options);
    optionsArr.push(document.getElementById("country").options);

    var optArrlenght = optionsArr.length;
    for ( var j = 0; j < optArrlenght; j++){
        var options = optionsArr[j];
        var optionslength = options.length
        for (var i = 0; i < optionslength; i++)
        {
            if (options[i].innerHTML == "Null Value" || options[i].innerHTML == "")
            {
                options.removeChild(options[i]);
                // OR
                // options.options[i] = null;
            }       

        }

    }

}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="change()">
Geography:<select id="Geography">

    <option value="0"></option>

    <option value="1">Null Value</option>

    <option value="2">item 2</option>

    <option value="3">item 3</option>

    <option value="4">item 4</option>

    <option value="0">All</option>

</select>
 zone:   <select id="zone" >

    <option value="0"></option>

    <option value="1">Null Value</option>

    <option value="2">item 2</option>

    <option value="3">item 3</option>

    <option value="4">item 4</option>

    <option value="0">All</option>

</select>

country:<select id="country" >

    <option value="0"></option>

    <option value="1">Null Value</option>


    <option value="2">item 2</option>

    <option value="3">item 3</option>

    <option value="4">item 4</option>

    <option value="0">All</option>

</select>
</body>
```

Comment: this will help check out..http://jsbin.com/awUWAMeN/1/edit

Comment: so u mention with value=1 so it remove but i dono where is null value present listbox at the time how to remove null value and space....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi whether u have found out solution or not still i put my answer here..

http://jsbin.com/awUWAMeN/2/edit

```
function change()
{
  $('select').each(function() {
    $(this).find('option:contains("Null Value")').remove();

});

}
```

Comment: sry .its shown result in ur case fine but i also so done same no result

Answer (score 0):

This is not the proper way to remove a dom element: [`.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) should be called on the elements parent. Instead of `options.removeChild(options[i]);`, try:

```
options[i].parentElement.removeChild(options[i]);
```

Also, if you want to remove the element from the array `options` call the following:

```
options.splice(i, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the following changes:

1.

```
<option value="0"></option>

<option value="Null Value">Null Value</option>

<option value="item 2">item 2</option>

<option value="item 3">item 3</option>

<option value="item 4">item 4</option>

<option value="All">All</option>
```

2.Inside Loop in function change you need to do following

```
     if (options[i].value == "Null Value" ) 
     { options.removeChild(options[i]);}   

     if(options[i].innerHTML == "") 
    {     options.removeChild(options[i])}
```

Comment: You need to enable javascript on the respective browser.